# Efficiently scanning a table based on indices from another table in PySpark and HBase

Tags: hbase, pyspark

I am new to PySpark here.
I have 2 tables, 1: Index table and 2: Value table shown in the image. 
[image: Table Images]

---

I want to know an efficient way of doing the following:

- Run a scan through table 1, and get the index
- Run a scan through table 2, and get values corresponding to the given index

---

And then I have multiple such (Key - Index) tables and (Index-Value) tables.
Please let me know the most efficient and PySpark way of doing these scans.
I want to know a way of doing:

---

`rdd1 = scan 'table1' {FILTER => key ='some value'} # Will get Index values
 rdd2 = scan 'table2', {STARTROW => The Results of table 1}`

So, if rdd1 returns 10 rows, then, the values in the Index field of those 10 rows will be used to scan table2 and get the Values from table2.
This is making me run 10 scans on table2 sequentially, and is ending up consuming a lot of time.
I want to know a way to parallelize the scans on table2,
`rdd1.map(lamba x: scan table2`
is giving me errors, as I end up having a scan inside of a scan, and I cannot do that.
Please suggest any alternative methods, if you think it would be more efficient.
Thanks

Comment: Please remove images and post it as sample data. Also show what you have tried and what errors you are getting. "we are not allowed to do : rdd.map(anotherRDD) " doesnt make sense? and efficiency is subjective term.

Comment: @Pushkr I have tried to elaborate a bit, but I cannot share the data here. Please let me know if you are still finding it confusing, I will definitely explain the whole situation as clearly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

efficient and simple way of doing what you want is using `Dataframes` and not rdd

lets say you have data which look like this -

```
table1 = [(1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C'),(4,'B')]
table2 = [('A',10),('B',20),('D',30),('E',40)]

# create the dataframes based on the data 
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(table1,schema=['k1','v1'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(table2,schema=['k2','v2'])

df1.show() 
+---+---+
| k1| v1|
+---+---+
|  1|  A|
|  2|  B|
|  3|  C|
|  4|  B|
+---+---+

 df2.show() 
+---+---+
| k2| v2|
+---+---+
|  A| 10|
|  B| 20|
|  D| 30|
|  E| 40|
+---+---+

# do a simple inner join and only select df2 columns
df2\
.join(df1, df1.v1==df2.k2)\
.select(df2.columns)\
.dropDuplicates()
.show()

+---+---+
| k2| v2|
+---+---+
|  B| 20|
|  A| 10|
+---+---+
```

just using Rdds -

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize(table1)
rdd2 = sc.parallelize(table2)

rdd2\
.join(rdd1.map(lambda x : (x[1],x[0])))\
.mapValues(lambda x: x[0])\
.distinct()\
.collect()
```

Comment: Hey @pushkr, I appreciate your solution. 
I have a requirement to keep the data in the form of rdds. Also, I will definitely look into inner joins. 
Thanks for suggesting. If you are still interested in this, I can share some actual tables I have, and probably you could suggest a solution.

Comment: Updated using just rdds.

Comment: Thanks @Pushkr So this solution works if you already have rdd2.
What if I do not have table2 as  rdd2, but have to use the scan command (using STARTROW and ENDROW from  each row of rdd1)?
I cannot use join if I have not scanned and stored table2 as an rdd yet, right? 
I want only those rows from table2 which have their k2 value lying in v1.

Comment: what do you mean? rdd2 is your 2nd table data which has index and values.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43548858/scan-a-hadoop-database-table-in-spark-using-indices-from-an-rdd