# Scan a Hadoop Database table in Spark using indices from an RDD

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, pyspark, rdd

So if there is a table in the database shown as below:

---

`Key2   DateTimeAge
AAA1    XXX XXX XXX
AAA2    XXX XXX XXX
AAA3    XXX XXX XXX
AAA4    XXX XXX XXX
AAA5    XXX XXX XXX
AAA6    XXX XXX XXX
AAA7    XXX XXX XXX
AAA8    XXX XXX XXX
BBB1    XXX XXX XXX
BBB2    XXX XXX XXX
BBB3    XXX XXX XXX
BBB4    XXX XXX XXX
BBB5    XXX XXX XXX
CCC1    XXX XXX XXX
CCC2    XXX XXX XXX
CCC3    XXX XXX XXX
CCC4    XXX XXX XXX
CCC5    XXX XXX XXX
CCC6    XXX XXX XXX
CCC7    XXX XXX XXX
DDD1    XXX XXX XXX
DDD2    XXX XXX XXX
DDD3    XXX XXX XXX
DDD4    XXX XXX XXX
DDD5    XXX XXX XXX
DDD6    XXX XXX XXX
DDD7    XXX XXX XXX`

I have a 2nd table, given as 

`1 AAA
2 DDD
3 CCC`

Since AAA,DDD and CCC are in table2, I want to scan all rows corresponding to these 3 values from table1, i.e, I want to get AAA1-AAA8, DDD1 -DDD7 and CCC1-CCC7. 
The table1 is a Hadoop database table, and has millions of rows. I only want to scan it for rows which I get from table1. 
Could anyone help me with an efficent way of doing this? I have table1 as an RDD, and table2 is in HBase.

Comment: @Pushkr Could you please have a look at this?

Comment: you need spark and hbase connector like https://github.com/Huawei-Spark/Spark-SQL-on-HBase to do hbase tables scans in spark..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficult part is actually to setup the HBase connector either from [Hortonworks](https://hortonworks.com/blog/spark-hbase-dataframe-based-hbase-connector/) or from [Huawei](https://github.com/Huawei-Spark/Spark-SQL-on-HBase).

But anyway I think you are asking about the query itself, so I have quickly built a toy example using Hive (i.e. creating the HBase table using the shell and then adding a `create external table` in Hive).

Then I create a SQL context using the Hive context.

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
```

The full toy table has 3 rows:

```
df = sqlContext.sql("select * from hbase_table_1")
df.show(3)
+----+--------+
| key|column_1|
+----+--------+
|AAA1|    abcd|
|AAA2|    efgh|
|BBB1|    jklm|
+----+--------+
```

and to access a subset of the HBase `rowkeys`:

```
df = sqlContext.sql("select * from hbase_table_1 where key >= 'AAA' and key < 'BBB'")
df.show(3)
+----+--------+
| key|column_1|
+----+--------+
|AAA1|    abcd|
|AAA2|    efgh|
+----+--------+
```

For performance you should definitively go for one of the HBase connectors, but once you have it (at least for Hortonworks') the query should be the same.