# Hbase connection with Pyspark

Tags: hbase, pyspark, connector

Please, I want to connect Hbase with Pyspark using a connector. I've tried several ways but It doesn't seem to work. Can you help me

Comment: Can you provide more information like what "ways" you use and which problems you encountered. Otherwise no one can help you.

Comment: I tried to use this jar " spark-hbase-connector-2.10-0.9.jar " but It works only for scala, and I need to make it work for pyspark. So please what are the structure of the commands I should use to make it work for pyspark

Comment: If your HBase table is in Hive you don't need much, however it is not good for performance (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43563207/3519000)). You should go for Hortonworks or Huawei connectors, and from the name of the jar I guess you are using Huawei, see [here](https://github.com/Huawei-Spark/Spark-SQL-on-HBase#python-shell) for pyspark installation.